# How to validate functions in hardhat test

Tags: blockchain, solidity, chai, hardhat

Actually i am validating an function to check that only whitelisted members or owner can access this function but when i am running this test file i am getting reverting error that

**Error message**

```
Validations
         should revert error for non whitelisted memeber:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Only owner or whiteListed members allowed'
    at KeyboardNFT.isWhiteListedorOwner (contracts/nft_erc721.sol:1102)
```

**code**

```
describe("Validations", function () {
    it("should revert error for non whitelisted memeber", async function () {
      const {hardhatToken, owner, addr1, addr2} = await loadFixture(deployTokenFixture);
      expect(await hardhatToken.connect(addr1).awardItem(addr1.address,"first nft")).to.throw("Only owner or whiteListed members allowed");
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need pass the pending `Promise` as the argument of `expect()`
2. Use `expect().to.be.revertedWith()` (specific to Hardhat) instead of the generic Chai `expect().to.throw()`

```
await expect(
    hardhatToken.connect(addr1).awardItem(addr1.address, "first nft")
).to.revertedWith("Only owner or whiteListed members allowed");
```

Docs: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-chai-matchers/docs/overview#reverts